# Passing HTML string to render code snippets

Tags: node.js, twig, newline, indentation, code-snippets

I have [frontMatter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) HTML string examples for static generators like [Metalsmith](http://www.metalsmith.io/) or Hexo like this:

```
html: 
  code: "<a class=\"button-social\" href=\"#\">\n  <div class=\"button-social__icon\"><i class=\"fa fa-dashboard\"></i></div>\n  <div class=\"button-social__network\">Button</div>\n</a>"
  copy: "<a class=\"button-social\" href=\"#\">\n  <div class=\"button-social__icon\"><i class=\"fa fa-dashboard\"></i></div>\n  <div class=\"button-social__network\">Button</div>\n</a>"
  snippet: "<pre><code class=\"lang-html\">&lt;a class=&quot;button-social&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;\n  &lt;div class=&quot;button-social__icon&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-dashboard&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/div&gt;\n  &lt;div class=&quot;button-social__network&quot;&gt;Button&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;/a&gt;\n</code></pre>\n"
  source: "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button-social\">\n  <div class=\"button-social__icon\">\n    <i class=\"fa fa-dashboard\"></i>\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"button-social__network\">\n    Button\n  </div>\n</a>"
```

I would like to put `html.snippet` or `html.code` inside my page to show the code snippet, but I get everything **inline**.

So my final render is:

```
<a class="button-social" href="#"> <div class="button-social__icon"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></div> <div class="button-social__network">Button</div> </a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a class="button-social" href="#">
  <div class="button-social__icon"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></div>
  <div class="button-social__network">Button</div>
</a>
```

My Twig template is simply this and the code will be highlighted with [PrismJS](http://prismjs.com/):

```
<div class="snippet-code">
  <pre class="lang-html"><code>{{ html.code|raw }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

It seems I loose the newline for some reason, this is how source code looks like:

```
<pre><code class="lang-html"><a class="button-social" href="#"> <div class="button-social__icon"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></div> <div class="button-social__network">Button</div> </a></code></pre>
```

How can I **avoid to loose the newline** to see the code with it's indentation?

Comment: Did you also try: `{{ html.code|raw|nl2br }}`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [new line 2 break filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html) like this:

```
<div class="snippet-code">
  <pre class="lang-html">
    <code>
     {{ html.snippet|raw|nl2br }}
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

but that inserts the `<br/>` tag. I'm not sure if that works for you?

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't remove the problem, maybe I'm missing something to keep the newlines?

Comment: I updated my post. Try adding the `raw` filter, and also I think it needs to be `html.snippet`. Also, did you clear your cache by running: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`?

Comment: It seems I'm loosing new lines for some reason, I've updated the question